# how to add S3 authentication keys AWS SDK PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, composer-php

I do not understand where I am supposed to add my key and secret key credentials. I am using AWS SDK for php with composer. The documentation says to create a credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials.

I do not understand the filepath. Where exactly to I make this file? Do I make it at the root of the folder I am in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Unix filepath and means "in the homefolder, in .aws/credentials".

I assume you use Windows. In this case, use that path:

```
  C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials
```

"credentials" is a text file, which you could edit with Notepad.
".aws" is just the name of folder which you can create with Explorer.
USERNAME is your Windows-Username.

You can [read about it in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).

If you are on a Mac, like indicated in the comment, you can do the following:

- Open the Terminal.app and type: `mkdir ~/.aws`. This will create a new folder in your home folder
- Then type: `open ~/.aws`. This will open a Finder inside the .aws Folder. Then you can work usign the finder to create a file called "credentials"
- OR: If you have Sublime Text installed, type: `subl ~/.aws`
- OR: If you are familiar with VI, type: `vi ~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: I am on a mac. I have seen the documentation, but that is what I don't understand. I know its simple, but I still don't get it. I'm looking for the path of home\users\ then make the .aws folder and then the credentials file?

Comment: @figaro: In the top menu bar, click on Go > Home. Create `.aws` directory and proceed further.

Comment: Thank you, but it says it cannot create a folder starting with a .

Comment: @figaro if you are on a mac, then open the terminal, and type: mkdir ~/.aws. I updated my answer to help you further.

Comment: well thank you for the details....makes more sense. I still can't get it to authenticate for me. I suspect that is because of more issues. God I really hate how hard they make this. Thank you for replying.

Comment: You are welcome. If you can't get in check the IAM. Usually you have to add some policies so you are account and its things is allowed to access the resources. Good luck... once you figured it out one time it's getting easier.